# How do I print only DOM content outside an Iframe using the window.print() function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Given an HTML page such as this:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="main">
  <div class="content1">
    <h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quos laborum commodi repudiandae, aspernatur vero nemo exercitationem at sapiente. Unde ex reiciendis inventore distinctio iure consequuntur amet optio ea, non omnis?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="content2">
    <iframe src="demo_iframe.html" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to print just the content including relevant styles, that are not inside an iframe. In this case just the content inside the `content1` div tag. How do I manipulate the DOM to achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: `let content1_content = document.getElementsByClassName('content1')[0].innerHTML; document.print( content1_content );`

Comment: Thanks for this. But I am getting the error: `VM60:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.print is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:10`

Comment: it should probably be window.print instead. do i have to do everything for you here? you had it right in the title of your question :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print

Comment: `window.print(content1_content)` prints the entire page. I want the Iframe content to be excluded

Comment: no, `window.print(content1_content)` will print whatever is in `content1_content`and the code i gave you specifies that `content1_content` is equal to the inner html of the div. content1 the iframe isn't being printed. it is perhaps already there, but it's not being printed given that it's not inside of div.content1

Comment: You're gonna have to elaborate and be more specific if you want a better answer than that one i've provided in the above comment. as far as i'm concerned that's specifically what you've asked to do & i don't know where the confusion is coming from

Comment: `window.print(content1_content)` prints the entire page. I wish I could upload a picture here so you see it. You can try is yourself, by running the code in the console of your browser

Comment: Maybe you could demonstrate the behavior in your question by adding a snippet? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193323/how-to-enter-code-snippets-in-posts-on-stack-overflow

Comment: This is the snippet I ran on the console
```let content1_content = document.getElementsByClassName('content1')[0].innerHTML; 
document.print( content1_content );
```